# Exec upsert statement with gorm and raw clauses

Tags: go-gorm

I have a function to upsert a rank in my table. This statement does not return anything.

But I am not sure which finalizer I should use. There is no `Exec` to just execute the given clauses.

```
func RankInsert(db *gorm.DB, rank uint, rId uint, uId uint) error {
    i := clause.Insert{
        Table: clause.Table{Name: "rank_recipe", Alias: "rr"},
    }

    v := clause.Values{
        Columns: []clause.Column{
            {Name: "recipe", Table: "rr"},
            {Name: "creator", Table: "rr"},
            {Name: "rank", Table: "rr"},
        },
        Values: [][]interface{}{
            {rId},
            {uId},
            {rank},
        },
    }

    c := clause.OnConflict{
        Columns: []clause.Column{
            {Name: "recipe", Table: "rr"},
            {Name: "creator", Table: "rr"},
        },
        DoUpdates: clause.Set{{
            Column: clause.Column{Name: "rank"},
            Value:  "EXCLUDED.rank",
        }},
    }

    return db.Clauses(i, v, c).Row().Err()
    //query := `INSERT INTO "rank_recipe" (recipe, creator, rank) VALUES($1, $2, $3) ON CONFLICT (recipe, creator) DO UPDATE SET rank = EXCLUDED.rank`
    //return db.Exec(query, rId, uId, rank).Error
}
```